# VBA: Convert Formula to values for a file with 260 Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert all cells in my workbook from formulas to values.
For this I wanted to use the code you see below, but even though it worked for smaller files I get an "error 1004" for the xlPasteValues when I use it for the file with 260 worksheets.

```
Sub Formula_Zapper() 
Worksheets.Select 
Cells.Select 
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
ActiveSheet.Select 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain to me why it doesnt work for the big file and how I can work around this?

I tried to work around it by selecting less worksheets and do multiple rounds, but then I have the problem that I dont want to make a manual array where I manually add the worksheets I want to select in this round.

I also tried to use a For-Loop and select one worksheet after the other, but my pc crashes when i try to do so. Is there a way to tell VBA to select worksheet 1 to 50 at the same time?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm really kind of lost here.

Comment: What do your worksheets look like?  do they all have the same range filled in them?  If so, you can make a loop that selects a smaller range.  Also, if you use a specific range you can avoid using the select and copy methods by doing something like this.  `sheets(1).range("A1:D30").value = sheets(1).range("A1:D30").value` If the range isn't the same, but it is easy to define with simple VBA code, you can loop through the sheets with the used range for each sheet and then convernting to values using the before mentioned code.

Comment: The worksheets always look the same but probably have a range of 2000x2000 cells of data. The file is just huge, thats why my pc just crashes down when I loop through the files. when I tried the .value method, excel for some reason just filled some lines with "0"s. I dont know why.

Comment: using the .value method did it crash?  or was the only problem that it filled the lines with 0's?

Comment: the only problem was that it filled in 0's.

Comment: Is there anything consistent about the formatting or kind of formulas in the rows that were turned to 0's?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way that does not use `Range.Copy`

```
Sub ReplaceFormulaeWithValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook
        ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one Thomas!!